# How to set the parsing query result range without knowing the number of records?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I run SQL query in excel through excel-vba& ADO. 
I parse the result using looping
Then ,i find that i have to know how many records sql will generate before parsing the result .

In reality , I　don't know the numbers of query result records before generating the query .

Any functions or method can let me know so that i can put on the loop statement ?

(i have got insight of .Fields() .Properties() ,but not work )

```
Sub sbADO()
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String



DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
'DBPath ="C:\InputData.xlsx"

sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

Conn.Open sconnect
      sSQLSting =  select ....' it is too long so i choose to skip

    Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)



    Do While Not rs.EOF




'Officer = rs.Fields(i).Value
For j = 5 To 29  ' THIS IS THE MAIN CODE I NEED TO IMPROVE
'worksheet1.Cells(7, 11) = rs.Properties.Count
worksheet1.Cells(j, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
worksheet1.Cells(j, 3) = rs.Fields(2).Value
worksheet1.Cells(j, 4) = rs.Fields(3).Value
worksheet1.Cells(j, 7) = rs.Fields(6).Value



    ' Insert data to your worksheet here




  rs.MoveNext
 Next j


Loop


rs.Close




End Sub
```

---

```
    For j = 5 To 29  ' 
next j
```

This is the range I should set that affect the range of worksheet parsing .There is totally 24 numbers of query record result in this case .If I set j  too large (e.g. To 30), it will prompt out 3021 error -BOF & EOF should be true .Hence , the range should fit the numbers of record well .

Comment: You just need to increment `j` inside of your `Do While Not rs.EOF` loop.  You don't need the `For j...` loop at all.

Comment: MS Excel Range supports `CopyFromRecordset` method, which is very handy.

Comment: @ Maciej Los i cant  use `CopyFromRecordset` .Some columns i have to score data in excel .The sql will reset all my data stored before

Comment: @ Tim Williams  i tried `j=5  worksheet1.Cells(j, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
worksheet1.Cells(j, 3) = rs.Fields(2).Value
worksheet1.Cells(j, 4) = rs.Fields(3).Value
worksheet1.Cells(j, 7) = rs.Fields(6).Value j=j+1
  rs.MoveNext
 Next j


Loop


rs.Close




End Sub` But it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for j.  Just increment j after all the cell assignments and before the end of the do loop.

```
Sub sbADO()
    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
    'DBPath ="C:\InputData.xlsx"

    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

    Conn.Open sconnect
    sSQLSting =  select ....  ' it is too long so i choose to skip

    Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)
    j = 5
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        'worksheet1.Cells(7, 11) = rs.Properties.Count
        worksheet1.Cells(j, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
        worksheet1.Cells(j, 3) = rs.Fields(2).Value
        worksheet1.Cells(j, 4) = rs.Fields(3).Value
        worksheet1.Cells(j, 7) = rs.Fields(6).Value
        j = j + 1
        rs.MoveNext

    Loop

    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: just a simple question . Is it no need to define (dim) before assigning the variable in VBA ,unlike JAVA ,c  ?I m referring to the j

Comment: By default no.  But if you add `Option Explicit` to the top of the code module than all the variables must be declared.  I always use `Option Explicit` it helps the invoker catch errors early.

Comment: by default no  ,do u mean integer ? is it able to store double ,long ?

Comment: If `Option Explicit` is at the top of the code module all variables need to be declared before the can be used.  Basically the `Invoker` is called when you compile you code.  It complains if it finds any syntax errors or bad assignments.  I really don't know that much about it, yet.